# How to get notified at a certain time

Tags: android, publish-subscribe

I would like to implement a system in order to get notified at a certain time. This should happen even if the user is not using the app. Is there a kind of "android service" that I have to subscribe for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). It is, roughly speaking, analogous to **`cron`** on OS X/Linux.

Comment: I thought to use that, but what happen if the user is not using the app? ie. The user is turning on the device and the time set in the app is expired. How the app can get notified if the user is not using it?

Comment: @DanieleVitali: "but what happen if the user is not using the app?" -- any scheduled events in `AlarmManager` still happen. "The user is turning on the device and the time set in the app is expired" -- by definition, if the device is off, no code is running, **because the device is off**. Your `AlarmManager` schedule is wiped out when the device is turned off. When the user turns their device back on again, you can get control at boot time to both reschedule any `AlarmManager` events and, if needed, take some background actions if an event occurred while the device is off.